# UWP XAML Frame.Navigate para página com parâmetro

Tags: parâmetros, xaml, uwp

Tenho duas páginas e quero navegar de uma pra outra. Só que a segunda página tem um parâmetro que deve ser recebido da primeira.

```
...
class MainPage
{
    MainPage()
    {
        InitializaComponent();
    }

    public void ok_buttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage));
    }
}

class SecondPage
{
    SecondPage(int item)
    {
        InitializaComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ficaria assim:

```
class MainPage
{
    MainPage()
    {
        InitializaComponent();
    }

    public void ok_buttonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var param = "Valor";
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), param);
    }
}
```

**Página 2**

```
class SecondPage
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e.Parameter);
    }
}
```